# Default selection of radio button in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the code below. The intended behaviour is to set the default option in a set of radio buttons. I've used very similar code elsewhere and its worked but in this case the last 3 options are all showing as selected. I'm new to tkinter and can't for the life of me see where I've gone wrong. Any help much appreciated.

```
charttypevar=StringVar()

chart_type_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(chart_type_frame, text="3d with catagories",variable=charttypevar,value='3d with catagories')#
chart_type_2 = ttk.Radiobutton(chart_type_frame, text="3d no catagories",variable=charttypevar,value='3d no catagories')#
chart_type_3 = ttk.Radiobutton(chart_type_frame, text="3d relief plot", variable=charttypevar, value='3d relief plot')  #
chart_type_4=ttk.Radiobutton(chart_type_frame,text="Not yet defined",variable=charttypevar,value="Not yet defined")
charttypevar.set('Not yet defined')  # intended to be set as default

chart_type_1.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky="W")
chart_type_2.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky="W")
chart_type_3.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky="W")
chart_type_4.grid(column=0,row=4,sticky="W")
```

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and follow its advice. Things like knowing whether this code is inside a class or function, and how and when you call this code is important.

Comment: I can't recreate your problem using this part of code - maybe problem is in different part of code.

Comment: i think its to do with a previous dialogue box with the same name - changing the root has solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

You didnt share the completed code. Yet this solves your problem. What is "ttk"? If you imported tkinter as "ttk" why dont you use it when defining the stringvar too?

```
import tkinter as ttk
chart_type_frame=Tk()
charttypevar=ttk.StringVar()

chart_type_1 = ttk.Radiobutton(chart_type_frame, text="3d with catagories",variable=charttypevar,value='3d with catagories')#
chart_type_2 = ttk.Radiobutton(chart_type_frame, text="3d no catagories",variable=charttypevar,value='3d no catagories')#
chart_type_3 = ttk.Radiobutton(chart_type_frame, text="3d relief plot", variable=charttypevar, value='3d relief plot')  #
chart_type_4=ttk.Radiobutton(chart_type_frame,text="Not yet defined",variable=charttypevar,value="Not yet defined")
charttypevar.set('Not yet defined')  # intended to be set as default

chart_type_1.grid(column=0,row=1,sticky="W")
chart_type_2.grid(column=0,row=2,sticky="W")
chart_type_3.grid(column=0,row=3,sticky="W")
chart_type_4.grid(column=0,row=4,sticky="W")
```

Comment: Thanks - In the code i've got imports as follows

        import tkinter as ttk
        from tkinter import *

I've also got 

   root = Tk()
and have a frame called outerframe, which contains another frame called chart_type_frame but not sure if this is where the issue is as it replicates code i've used elsewhere which behaves as expected

Comment: You dont need to import tkinter twice. Only "import tkinter as ttk" will be enough. Check out the code, its working fine.

Comment: importing tkinter "as ttk" is bad advice. There is an existing module named "ttk" with very similar widgets, so anybody reading the code without closely examining the imports will be very confused.

Comment: It wasnt my advice actually. If you check his comment or code he imported it like that. But you are right.